# jscript IntelliSense is not working and jscript is not listed as a Text Editor language in VS2008

Tags: javascript-intellisense

I am using VS2008 Version 3.5 SP1 and IntelliSense is not working for JScript. Also, JScript is not even listed as a language under Tools->Options->Text Editor. Do I need to do something special to define JScript as a language under VS2008?